# How would I make weapon bobbing like Counter Strike: Global Offsenive?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, viewmodel

I have recently been working on a weapon system and I have hit a problem, bobbing. I have looked at various articles and view bobbing scripts but none of them have worked for me. I have wrote some code however it doesn't do what I have in mind.
Code:

```
private void Bobbing()
    {
        if(verticalInput != 0 || horizontalInput != 0)
        {
            float theta = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad / bobbingSpeed;
            float Xdistance = bobbingXAmount * Mathf.Sin(theta);
            float Ydistance = bobbingYAmount * Mathf.Sin(theta);

            bobPos = new Vector3(Xdistance, Ydistance, 0);
            
        }
        else
        {
            float theta = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad / bobbingSpeed;
            float distance = 0f * Mathf.Sin(theta);

            bobPos = Vector3.up * distance;
        }
    }
```

I have looked at articles and tutorials. I am expecting a CSGO style weapon/viewmodel bob.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DR4fTllQnXg

Answer (score 0):

Depending how you set up your camera and if your character is a full body rig character or just the hand, you could try:

1.) Animating manually for the hand movement while in running animation is playing.
2.) Add an animation event at every footstep to trigger a tween movement of the hand position through code.

The free DOTween package can be found here: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/dotween-hotween-v2-27676